# How to change the width of the thumb in a HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I'm using the thumb of the horizontal scroll view to indicate which page the user is on. What I would like to happen is the thumb width be the screenwidth/number of pages which is what happens on larger devices. The problem comes when I switch to a phone: the thumb width is no longer the size it's bigger which I cannot use.

Is there a way to change the width of the thumb in a horizontal scroll view (or the hight in a vertical scroll view)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. You cannot change the actual scrollviews scrollbars because you need the class ScrollBarDrawable which isn't in the ADK. So what I did was overrode the scrollview and drew a custom scrollbar. Also make sure to disable the scrollviews default scrollbars (View.setVericalScrollbarEnabled(boolean) or android:scrollbars="none")

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w,h,oldw,oldh);
    width = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();

    //you need this to get the total width of the scrollview (with all of the children) 
    measure(w,h);
    totalWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
}



@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    float xPer = getScrollX() / totalWidth;
    canvas.drawRect(
            (xPer * width) + getScrollX(),
            getHeight() - scrollBarHeight,
            //scroll position   //width of the bar      //offset in the actual canvas
            ((xPer * width) + (width/(totalWidth/width)) + getScrollX(),
            getHeight(), paint);
}
```

Hope this helps someone else!